# MySQL - How to split values in single strings using comma

Tags: mysql

I have MySql (8.0) with two tables, main:

```
 ID | TITLE | kindof
 1  |  aaa  |  shop
 2  |  bbb  |  food 
 3  |  ccc  |  market
```

category:

```
 ID | TITLE | CATEGORY
 1  |  aaa  |  design, home, clothing
 2  |  bbb  |  asian, indian 
 3  |  ccc  |  second hand
```

my node/express (main ID is auto increment):

let sql = `BEGIN; INSERT INTO main (title,kindof) VALUES("${[req.body.title]}","${req.body.kindof});  INSERT INTO categories (id,title,category) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),"${[req.body.title]}"," ${[req.body.categories]}"); COMMIT;`;

I would like to have:

```
 ID | TITLE | CATEGORY
 1  |  aaa  |  design
 1  |  aaa  |  home
 1  |  aaa  |  clothing
 2  |  bbb  |  asian
 2  |  bbb  |  indian
 3  |  ccc  |  second hand
```

`req.body.category` looks like that: `{design, home, clothing}`

How can I split the string using the comma in MySQL? Thanks

Comment: Specify MySQL version.

Comment: version 8.0 at least is written in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL 8+ you may use, for example,

```sql
SELECT category.ID, category.TITLE, TRIM(jsontable.value) CATEGORY
FROM category
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE( CONCAT('["', REPLACE(category.CATEGORY, ',', '","'), '"]'),
                       "$[*]" COLUMNS( value VARCHAR(254) PATH "$" )
                     ) AS jsontable
ORDER BY category.ID, jsontable.value;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b8d7bec28ba7a598bdb3aeda77bf16ac)

Comment: thanks. your solution looks smoother. basicaly you trim them afterwards right?

Comment: your solution works perfectly! Thanks! what I don't understand is: is this a "filter" for when I want to get the categories?

Comment: @MarcoDisco I don't understand your question. This code unpivots your CSV data only. Put it into CTE (removing ORDER BY, of course), and then use obtained data as you need. As a filter, as a data table for joining, etc.

Comment: @MarcoDisco For your MySQL version you may also use the solution provided by Strawberry, after replacing static numbers table (`ints`) with recursive CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following. I have table (ints) of integers (i) from 0 to 9...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ints;

CREATE TABLE ints(i INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO ints VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS category;

CREATE TABLE category
(id INT NOT NULL
,title VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,category VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO category VALUES
(1,'aaa','design, home, clothing'),
(2,'bbb','asian, indian'),
(3,'ccc','second hand');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS main_category;

CREATE TABLE main_category
AS
SELECT DISTINCT id 
              , TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(category,',',i+1),',',-1)) category
           FROM category 
              , ints;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS category;


ALTER TABLE main_category ADD PRIMARY KEY(id,category);

SELECT * FROM main_category;
+----+-------------+
| id | category    |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | design      |
|  2 | asian       |
|  3 | second hand |
|  1 | home        |
|  2 | indian      |
|  1 | clothing    |
+----+-------------+
```

Comment: thanks! So if I understood: you want to create a new table `main_category` where insert the trimmed values?

Comment: Well, no. If it was me, I'd have table of 'mains', a table of 'categories', and a table which records which 'category' belongs to which 'main'. But you should be allowed to do whatever you want.

Comment: I meant that a table (main_category) that joins the two

Comment: Yes, but it would hold the id of the main, and the id of the category. My table is a stepping stone towards that, if you like.

Comment: sure, I want to keep that. Just the i+1 doesn't work. but let me try better

Comment: I've added the ints table for clarity. Note, if you're using MySQL 8.0+ then it's not strictly necessary.