# Binding an unknown number of keywords to a SQL statement with wildcards

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I want to bind keywords to a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT `field_1`, `field2` FROM `table` WHERE 
`field_1` LIKE '%keyword1%' 
OR `field_1` LIKE '%keyword2%'
OR `field_1` LIKE '%keyword3%'
```

Note that the number of keywords is NOT predetermined. It is in fact determined by an array which itself is determined by exploding user's input on space.

I am using Laravel 7. So, I am looking for a solution that is consistent with Laravel 7 and PDO. The problem is that I can't use `'%?%'` in my SQL statement  because then I won't be able to bind the values in my array to it.

I am sure there should be a solution for this as it seems like a common problem in writing simple search engines, but I can't find it on my own.

Comment: You should add the `%` to the value instead of the statement. So the statement is just: `LIKE ?` and then pass in the value like this: `"%$keyword%"`. So with Laravels query builder, it should be something like: `->orWhere('field_1', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")` and so on

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yup. Good idea. You could post it as an answer if you'll want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel-5 'LIKE' equivalent (Eloquent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761950/laravel-5-like-equivalent-eloquent)

Comment: No need. It's already been asked and answered a few times already. Added one of them as a duplicate instead.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I don't see how that question you posted is the same though. I mean here the number of keywords is indeterminate, but it seems to me that in that question it is fixed.

Comment: Just add as many `->orWhere()` you need. `->orWhere('foo', 'LIKE', "%$var1%")->orWhere('foo', 'LIKE', "%$var2%")`.

Comment: But I don't know how many orWhere() I should add beforehand. It's determined by the user input.

Comment: What is your MySQL version? Maybe it allows to transfer the keywords array as one CSV string literal and parse it in the query?

Comment: @Akina It's 5.7.28

Comment: I've added an answer including how you could add an unknown number of orWhere to the query.

Comment: This version does not support constructions which allows to parse CSV easily... Does function LOCATE/INSTR instead of LIKE operator usage is safe for you? *the number of keywords is NOT predetermined.* But there exists some upper keywords count limit maybe? for example, not more than 100 keywords... or maybe it can be set hardcoded? Does there exists some char which may be used as keywords delimiter (for example, a comma) which cannot be met in a keyword?

Comment: @Akina Thanks anyway. What version of MySQL supports that? Nevertheless, if you know a solution using that, please do post it. I can always upgrade MySQL on my server and I'll learn something new about MySQL as well.

Comment: You may see CSV parsing method, for example, [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62637258/10138734). It allows to combine all needed keywords into one CSV string which is parsed in a query, and a column value is then checked against each keyword separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your example query, you need to add the `%` to the value instead of the statement so it's like this:

```
WHERE foo LIKE ? OR foo LIKE ?
```

And then pass the values as `"%$var1%"`, `"%$var2%"` and so on.

#### Using Laravels Query Builder

Make sure you have all the search words in an array. Then you can, in Laravels (which you mentioned you're using) query builder, do something like this:

```
$searchWords = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'];

// Now get the query builder and pass closure as the argument
$query = DB::table('some-table')
    ->where(function($query) use ($searchWords) {
        // Iterate through the words and add them one by one
        foreach ($searchWords as $word) {
            $query->orWhere('field', 'LIKE', "%{$word}%");
        }
    });

$result = $query->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a good answer and I learned something new from this answer. I still need some time to understand how the part where it says ```function($query) use ($searchWords) {}``` word. It seems that you are generating PHP code using Laravel. Right? I have never seen that before. Do you know a place where I can read and learn more about it?

Comment: @stressedout - I'm not sure what you mean by "generating PHP code using Laravel". Laravel is just PHP code as well. The `function ($foo) use ($bar) {...}` is just an [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (also referred to as a Closure) that inherits the variable `$searchWords` from the outer scope. If the answer helped you to solve the problem, feel free to accept it to let others know it's been resolved.

Comment: We need an indeterminate number of ```orWhere()``` in our code. Right? So, our code should change based on user's input and add as many ```orWhere()``` as necessary. That's what I meant by "generating PHP code". My confusion is that I have never seen a syntax like ```function($arg1) use ($arg2){}```. That's why I can't understand your code yet. I will definitely accept your answer when I understand how it works.

Comment: If you read about anonymous classes in PHP ([here's the manual about them](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)), it will be clearer what it does. When adding the first `where()`, we pass in an anonymous function (Laravel's `where()` method supports this). Laravel will then run that function and pass the query instance as an argument `($query)`. Then it will also inherit the array (`use ($searchWords)`) so it can use it inside the function. The code in the function just iterates through the array of search words and adds a new `->orWhere()` to the query for each word.