# Convert CLOB column data translated to NUMBER field

Tags: sql, regex, oracle-sqldeveloper, clob

I am using ORACLE SQL Developer. I have a table Clob_tab haveing column with data type as: Col1 CLOB
data in this column is ('27,88,100,25,26')

I want to use this value from this column as subquery into another query:
select * from Abc where Col2 not in (select Col1 from Clob_tab );
DATATYPE of Col2 is NUMBER.
I want output as :
select * from Abc where Col2 not in (27,88,100,25,26);

Is it possible?

I have tried multiple things which are not working like:
Convert blob to  varchar2 : dbms_lob.substr(MY_FIELD_BLOB_TYPE)
Convert varchar2 to Number using regex_replace: select cast(regexp_replace(Col1 , '[^0-9]+', '') as number) from Clob_tab  .
Using regex_repalce all the commas are disappearing and I am getting 27881002526. I don't want this number. I want the numbers separated by commas.

None of them gives/translates my query to this form:

select * from Abc where Col2 not in (27,88,100,25,26);

Comment: You write: *Col1 CLOB data in this column is `('27,88,100,25,26')`*. Pay attention - this is ONE value. You write *where Col2 not in `(27,88,100,25,26)`;*. Pay attention - this is a LIST of values. Convert your CSV string to rowset. For example, you may add square brackets converting CSV to JSON ARRAY, and apply JSON_TABLE() function...

Comment: @Akina Can u please explain with an example how can I do this conversation in sqldeveloper

Comment: You could use dynamic SQL but that's a bit messy and potentially dangerous; plus if you're using a CLOB that suggests you expect a *lot* of values, and `in()` is limited to 1000 values. Otherwise you need to tokenize the string value into individual elements. Roughly how many rows are involved in each table, and if there are multiple rows in clob_tab how are they related to abc rows? And which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: the values i will be expecting in the subquery are max 10-15 values(numbers).

Comment: I use neither OracleDatabase nor SQLDeveloper. An example of `JSON_TABLE()` usage as it is applied in MySQL for CSV parsing may be found, for example, [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62637258/10138734). I think it can be easily adopted (or maybe even used as-is).

Comment: Lets say i convert from blob to varchar2.result is string example '25,26,27,100'. Now i want the conversation which can convert this one string into multiple separated numbers.  25,26,27,100.

Comment: The JSON_TABLE not working in sql developer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to tokenzise your string; this uses regular expressions (but is likely to be slow; see comments below):

```
with cte (n) as (
  select to_number(regexp_substr(col1, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1))
  from clob_tab
  connect by level < regexp_count(col1, '(.*?)(,|$)')
)
select *
from abc
where col2 not in (
  select n from cte
);
```

This uses XMLTable to treat the values as a sequence and extract them:

```
select *
from abc
where col2 not in (
  select to_number(x.column_value)
  from clob_tab
  cross join xmltable (col1) x
);
```

Depending on your Oracle version you could probably do something similar with JSON rather than XML:

```
select *
from abc
where col2 not in (
  select x.n
  from clob_tab
  cross join json_table (json_array(col1 format json returning clob), '$[*]' columns n number path '$') x
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ywPDyKJb)

It's worth trying various approaches and comparing performance with your data.

---

As @MT0 reported in comments (included here in case those are deleted):

> The first (hierarchical) query has huge performance problems when the number of terms get large (especially if CLOB_TAB has more than one row). For a larger data-set this gives an indication of performance [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xwjCBlS_) Summary: regular expressions were so slow that the run failed when they were included, XML took 0.8s, JSON and sub-string matching both took < 0.1s. (Although more data is needed for an accurate comparison)

> Updated my fiddle to use a string splitting method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38372145/1509264) that avoids regular expressions and uses recursive queries (rather than hierarchical) and the string splitting appears to perform better than XML but worse than JSON or sub-string matching [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xJPAw1AR)

Comment: The final JSON query needs to use `json_array(col1 format json RETURNING CLOB)` when the input is a CLOB that exceeds 4000 characters. The first (hierarchical) query has huge performance problems when the number of terms get large (especially if `CLOB_TAB` has more than one row). For a larger data-set this gives an indication of performance [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xwjCBlS_) Summary: regular expressions were so slow that the run failed when they were included, XML took 0.8s, JSON and sub-string matching both took < 0.1s. (Although more data is needed for an accurate comparison)

Comment: Updated my fiddle to use a string splitting method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38372145/1509264) that avoids regular expressions and uses recursive queries (rather than hierarchical) and the string splitting appears to perform better than XML but worse than JSON or sub-string matching [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xJPAw1AR)

Comment: @MT0 - thanks, I've added that missing clause. I'm not surprised hierarchical is slow but didn't expect it to be quite that bad. I've copied your findings into the answer just in case the comments disappear - but feel free to undo that if you'd prefer them not to be there.

Comment: The hierarchical query was particularly bad with multiple input rows combined with multiple terms-per-row (in this case there were only 2 rows) as there is no correlation between the current and previous hierarchy level so the SQL engine will correlate the current level with ALL rows for the previous level of the hierarchy. When there are 2 rows then when `LEVEL=1` you get 2 rows of output, when `LEVEL=2` you get 2*2 = 4 rows of output (2 rows correlated with the 2 previous rows) and so, generally, when `LEVEL=n` you will get 2<sup>n</sup> rows of output which makes it incredibly inefficient.

Comment: The OP's real table might have a unique key for the prior and non-deterministic workaround, but even so, likely to be a slow option *8-)

Comment: To improve it you have to get the query to correlate each level of the hierarchy to only a single prior row. Commonly that would be by adding something like `and PRIOR id =  id and PRIOR SYS_GUID() is not null` but that has its own performance problems (you need to generate a GUID for every row) or by using a `LATERAL` join so that the hierarchical query only ever works with a single row of input (but even if you do that then regular expressions still tend to be an order of magnitude slower than simple string functions).

Answer (score 1):

Don't split the `CLOB` into a table of values; instead you can find a sub-string match for the terms within the `CLOB` (matching preceding and following delimiters to ensure you are matching complete terms):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   Abc a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   clob_tab c
         WHERE  ',' || c.col1 || ',' LIKE '%,' || a.Col2 || ',%'
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE clob_tab (col1) as
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB()
       || '27,88,100,25,26,210,2,3'
       || LISTAGG(','||(2999+LEVEL)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LEVEL)
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 800
UNION ALL
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB() || LISTAGG(LEVEL, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LEVEL)
FROM   DUAL
WHERE  LEVEL < 20
OR     LEVEL > 30
OR     LEVEL IN (23, 25, 27)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 200;

CREATE TABLE abc (col2) as
SELECT 20 + LEVEL
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
```

Outputs:

| COL2 |
| --- |
| 21 |
| 22 |
| 24 |
| 28 |
| 29 |
| 30 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lPTHsGCa)

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution to this problem :)

select regexp_substr(OBJECT_NAME,'[^,]+', 1, level) from prachi_exp_cycle connect by regexp_substr(OBJECT_NAME, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;

It will return the output as comma-separated char values 25,26,27.
These outputs will be auto-converted to number in SQL developer when used in as a subquery.