# How to convert CLOB to varchar , and separate them by comma

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Writing a plSQL script in oracle .
DM_CATEGORY  column's data type is varchar .
othertext column's datatype is CLOB, which return a comma separated data. e.g. FGOH,functional-parameter,disability-parameter,cognitive-parameter

Script
`where DM_CATEGORY in (select othertext from Preslists where tablename='tablename' and functionname='functionname' )`

How to pass this data in this in cluse?
getting this below error with this script
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Writing a plSQL script in oracle .
DM_CATEGORY  column's data type is varchar .
othertext column's datatype is CLOB, which return a comma separated data. e.g. FGOH,functional-parameter,disability-parameter,cognitive-parameter

Script
`where DM_CATEGORY in (select othertext from Preslists where tablename='tablename' and functionname='functionname' )`

How to pass this data in this in cluse?
getting this below error with this script
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Comment: Convert to varchar is not going to solve your problem. The CLOB value needs to be converted to a table of varchar values. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63262911/convert-clob-column-data-translated-to-number-field) post about a similar issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LIKE` with a sub-query and `EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   Preslists p
         WHERE  p.tablename = 'tablename' 
         AND    p.functionname='functionname'
         AND    ',' || p.othertext || ',' LIKE '%,' || t.DM_CATEGORY || ',%'
       );
```

or `DBMS_LOB.INSTR`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
WHERE  EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   Preslists p
         WHERE  p.tablename = 'tablename' 
         AND    p.functionname='functionname'
         AND    DBMS_LOB.INSTR(
                  ',' || p.othertext || ',',
                  ',' || t.DM_CATEGORY || ','
                ) > 0
       );
```

Which, for the sample output:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (dm_category) AS
SELECT 'W' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'X' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Z' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE preslists (othertext, tablename, functionname) AS
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB()
       || RPAD('A', 4000, 'A')
       || RPAD(',', 4000, 'B')
       || ',X,Y',
       'tablename',
       'functionname'
FROM   DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB()
       || RPAD('C', 4000, 'C')
       || RPAD(',', 4000, 'D')
       || ',Z,Y',
       'tablename',
       'functionname'
FROM   DUAL;
```

Both outputs:

| DM_CATEGORY |
| --- |
| X |
| Y |
| Z |

*Note: The `Y` value is not repeated even though it appears in both matching lists in `Preslists`; which is the same behaviour as if a value appears twice in an `IN` list.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/djIxQhZo)

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the CLOB to varchar:
Script: where **to_char(DM_CATEGORY)** in (select othertext from Preslists where tablename='tablename' and functionname='functionname' )

or:
dbms_lob.substr(DM_CATEGORY, 4000, 1)

while "4000" is the Varchar defined size.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe DBMS_LOB.INSTR() function could help:

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    categories (ID, DM_CATEGORY) AS
        ( Select 1, 'Category 1' From Dual Union All
          Select 2, 'Category 2' From Dual Union All
          Select 3, 'Category 3' From Dual Union All
          Select 4, 'Category 4' From Dual 
        ),
    preslists AS
        ( Select 101 "ID", 'TBL_1' "TABLENAME", 'FUNC_1' "FUNCTIONNAME", TO_CLOB('Category 1,FGOH,Category 2, functional-parameter, something else') "OTHERTEXT" From Dual Union All
          Select 102 "ID", 'TBL_2' "TABLENAME", 'FUNC_2' "FUNCTIONNAME", TO_CLOB('Category A,Category B,Category 3,something else') "OTHERTEXT" From Dual
        )
```

Used in Where clause

```sql
--    S Q L   (condition in Where clause)
Select     c.ID, c.DM_CATEGORY
From       categories c
Inner Join preslists p ON(p.TABLENAME = 'TBL_2' And 
                          p.FUNCTIONNAME = 'FUNC_2' )
Where      DBMS_LOB.InStr(',' || p.OTHERTEXT || ',', ',' || c.DM_CATEGORY || ',') > 0
```

... or with condition in Join's ON clause

```sql
--    S Q L   (condition in Join's ON clause)
Select     c.ID, c.DM_CATEGORY
From       categories c
Inner Join preslists p ON(p.TABLENAME = 'TBL_2' And 
                          p.FUNCTIONNAME = 'FUNC_2' And 
                          DBMS_LOB.InStr(',' || p.OTHERTEXT || ',', ',' || c.DM_CATEGORY || ',') > 0)
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
        ID DM_CATEGORY
---------- -----------
         3 Category 3     */
```

NOTE:
There are commas added at start and at the and of CLOB to be used when compared to your DM_CATEGORY column value (also with commas before and after) to avoid accidentaly wrong comparisons.Without it you could match eg. 'Category 3' with 'Category 333'. This way you are looking for ',Category 3,'.